# Connection between streamlit and google sheets make the app considerably slow

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cloud, streamlit

I have a very simple web app in streamlit. It is connected with google sheets. But these two lines make my app very slow!

> ```
> s=Spread(spreadsheetname,client=client)
> sh=client.open(spreadsheetname)
> ```

In every interaction, the streamlit run the whole code again, that’s why these two lines create problems. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: I’m not familiar with any thing you have show as being Google App Script.  Is this Streamlit?

Comment: Yes it is streamlit

Comment: Perhaps use native Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your app from re-running the entire code again, you can use [st.form](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/control-flow/st.form), [caching](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/experimental-cache-primitives), and/or [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state). Which one you should use really depends on the details of the broader use case -- i.e. are you hoping to click a button and then have the connection be set up (use a form)? Or are you hoping that the connection will be set up once per app run (use caching)?